# SharePoint List That Pulls From Other Lists

Tags: sharepoint, list

can someone point me in the direction as to how I would do the following:

I want to create a list, which pulls say (top 3) items from other lists (more than one), and displays them in one consolidated list.  Is this possible?  If so please point me in the direction as to how I can accomplish this, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I need is to pull from more than one list the same information such as
Title, Link. And I would only like the most (3) recent entries from each list. The other lists exist in the same site collection, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Oliver, 
  As long as all of your lists are in the same site collection, the Content Query Web Part should do what you want ([cite](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101741341033.aspx)). You'll need some expertise in XSLT to keep the top three list items displayed ([example](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx)). There's a lot that the CQWP doesn't do that would seem common sense, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have MOSS then what you need is the Content Query Web Part.

Answer (score 1):

Ray, I'm not sure how lookup fields will handle his two chief requirements: limiting return sets (top three items) or consolidating multiple lists into one data source. Lookup columns accept one list as a data source, and I'm not sure how you'd get it to accept many lists aside from custom code development.

Answer (score 0):

Without using custom code, you are going to have to use several dataquery or content query webparts and modify their xslt to show as one integrated display.

Personally I would create a custom control, hosted by a webpart that runs several CAML queries and displays the top results of each query.